# Как постоянно создавать новый TimerTick для таймеров в dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, таймер

При изменении значения следующего добавленного таймера меняются все. Нужно ли создавать новый Timer_Tick для каждого из добавленных таймеров или можно как-то обойтись.

```
 public partial class Monitor : Form
{
    DataSet ds;
    string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Woo1fy\source\repos\MJWork\MJWork\LocalDB.mdf;Integrated Security = True";
    SqlConnection sqlConnection;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter;
    SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder;
    string sql = "SELECT [Номер браслета],[Услуга],[Запуск],[Оставшееся время] FROM Monitor";
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    DataTable dtStopwatches = new DataTable();
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    DataGridView vendorsDataGridView = new DataGridView();
    Dictionary<int, Stopwatch> swDct = new Dictionary<int, Stopwatch>();
    int nextID = 0;

    private Point mouseOffset;
    private bool isMouseDown = false;

    public Monitor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("Номер браслета", typeof(int));
        dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("Услуга", typeof(string));
        dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("Оставшееся время", typeof(string));
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dtStopwatches;

        foreach (string buttonName in new string[] { "Старт", "Удаление" })
        {
            DataGridViewButtonColumn colTemp = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            colTemp.Name = buttonName + "Col";
            colTemp.HeaderText = buttonName;
            colTemp.Width = 50;
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colTemp);
        }

        timer1.Tick += (timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 50;
        timer1.Start();
    }


    public void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dtStopwatches.Rows.Add(Data.Number, Data.Name, nextID, "00:00.00");
        swDct.Add(nextID, new Stopwatch());
        nextID++;
        //  label1.Text = Data.Time;

        /*   if (dataGridView1.Controls.OfType<VScrollBar>().First().Visible)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("fsaf");
           } */

        //set autosize mode
        dataGridView1.Columns[5].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.ColumnHeader;
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (DataRow dRow in dtStopwatches.Rows)
        {
            var diff = Data.Time.Subtract(swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed);
            //  string elapsedString = swDct[(int)dRow["ID"]].Elapsed.ToString(@"hh\:mm");
            dRow["Оставшееся время"] = Convert.ToString(diff.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"));


            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //dataGridView1.Rows[i].Selected = false;
                for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.ColumnCount; j++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value != null)
                    {
                        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString().Contains("00:00:00"))
                        {
                            dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#32cd33");

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //       dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[5], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
        }

    }
```

Comment: обойтись чем? В чем проблема то?

Comment: `Нужно ли создавать новый Timer_Tick`, `timer1_Tick` - это метод, вы его определяете, а не создаете.

Comment: При нажатии на кнопку я создаю строку с обратным секундомером, при этом он принимает значение переменной из другой формы. К примеру, я создал одну строку, секундомер принял переменную со значением 2:00:00. Создаю 2-ую строку с другим значением переменной для следующего таймера. Все созданные таймеры меняют свое значение на значение той переменной, что я недавно изменил. Слишком сложно объяснить на словах, мне проще записать видеоматериал и отправить вам на e-mail... Простите, но спустя 2 дня я не нашёл ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Таймера достаточно одного. При каждом тике проходим в цикле по всем значениям и изменяем оставшееся время.

Набросал действующий пример приложения.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WinFormApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        DataTable dtStopwatches = new DataTable();
        DataGridView dataGridView1;

        DataGridViewButtonColumn startButtonColumn;
        DataGridViewButtonColumn deleteButtonColumn;

        public Form1()
        {
            Width = 800;
            dataGridView1 = new DataGridView { Parent = this, Dock = DockStyle.Top };

            dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("Номер товара", typeof(int));
            dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("Услуга", typeof(string));
            dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("Оставшееся время", typeof(TimeSpan));

            dtStopwatches.Columns.Add("started", typeof(bool)).ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = dtStopwatches;

            startButtonColumn = CreateButtonColumn("Старт");
            deleteButtonColumn = CreateButtonColumn("Удаление");

            dataGridView1.CellContentClick += DataGridView1_CellContentClick;
            dataGridView1.CellFormatting += DataGridView1_CellFormatting;

            timer1.Tick += timer1_Tick;
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        DataGridViewButtonColumn CreateButtonColumn(string buttonName)
        {
            var button = new DataGridViewButtonColumn();
            button.Name = buttonName + "ButtonColumn";
            button.HeaderText = buttonName;
            button.Width = 50;

            button.Text = buttonName;
            button.UseColumnTextForButtonValue = true;

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(button);
            return button;
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            var cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];
            if (cell.OwningColumn.Name == "Оставшееся время")
            {
                var value = cell.Value;
                if (value != DBNull.Value && value != null && (TimeSpan)value == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
                {
                    cell.Style.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#32cd33");
                }
            }
        }

        private void DataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0) // исключаем хедер
            {
                var buttonColumn = dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewButtonColumn;

                if (buttonColumn == startButtonColumn)
                {
                    var row = dtStopwatches.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                    row["Оставшееся время"] = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
                    row["started"] = true;
                }
                else if (buttonColumn == deleteButtonColumn)
                {
                    // тут действия по удалению
                    dtStopwatches.Rows[e.RowIndex]["started"] = false;
                }
            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataRow row in dtStopwatches.Rows)
            {
                var started = row["started"];

                if (started != DBNull.Value && (bool)started == true)
                {
                    var remainingTime = (TimeSpan)row["Оставшееся время"];
                    remainingTime = remainingTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                    row["Оставшееся время"] = remainingTime;

                    if (remainingTime <= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0))
                    {
                        row["started"] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `remainingTime = remainingTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));` таймер ведь не точно раз в секунду срабабывает, наверное, лучше было бы созранить в строку целевое время и показывать разницу между целевым и текущим временем.

Comment: @tym32167 - согласен, так будет лучше. Тем более, что у автора изначально у таймера был тик 50 мс. Оставим это ему как домашнее задание.